# ActiveX y control WebBrowser

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web que debe permitir el acceso a diferentes webs externas. La aplicación tiene los siguientes elementos: una barra de navegación para seleccionar que web mostrar y un contenedor que muestra la web seleccionada de manera embebida.
La pregunta es ¿es posible realizar una aplicación de este tipo utilizando ActiveX con un control WebBrowser?

Comment: ActiveX? Eso es tecnología obsoleta, y solo funcionaría en Internet Explorer. Estás seguro de que es ActiveX lo que quieres usar?

Comment: Lo se, está obsoleta, pero no encuentro una alternativa a ActiveX. Lo que necesito es una aplicación web que permita cargar diferentes páginas web desde ella (otros dominios, por lo que me daría un error de CROSS Origen. Pretencía montar un activeX y dentro del mismo un  webbrowser, lo que permitiría navegar a todos estos sitios.